# flash page flipping technology that support touch gesture or compatible with iPad

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Does anyone know a "flash example" or "fla file" or tutorial that is related to a flipping page in using Flash technology. I've seen a lot of page flipping flash website that has a page that you can virtually flip using flash. I want to create a similar flash site/magazine that has 5-10 page that hopefully supports the iPad's touch gesture. What approach would you recommend or a tutorial to get me started.

Thanks!

Comment: I removed the actionscript-2 tag, as there's no way you'll be using that in an iOS AIR application.  It's AS3-only.  That said, there are a lot of pre-made page-flippers (though they are mostly from the AS2 era, as that was the height of the page-flipper popularity).  If you find one you like, you could convert it to AS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with scriptocalypse.
That said:

Something like this?
http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/pageflipper/

You'll have to implement your own swipe gesture. But a regular finger down and drag ought to work.